Ошибки проверки и игнорирования сертификатов при работе через прокси в Golang
Пишу скрипт на GO который проверяет прокси низкого качества путем выполнения GET запроса. Однако возникают ошибки с проверкой и игнорированием проверки сертификатов. Независимо к какому сайту выполняется запрос, ошибка сохраняется (сайт в коде для примера, пробовал и гугл и тд.).
import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

/* ... */

func main() {
    proxyList, err := readProxyFile("https.txt")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error reading proxy file:", err)
        return
    }

    for _, proxyStr := range proxyList {
        proxyURL, err := url.Parse("https://" + proxyStr)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error parsing proxy URL:", err)
            continue
        }

        httpTransport := &http.Transport{
            Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyURL),
            DialContext: (&net.Dialer{
                Timeout:   30 * time.Second,
                KeepAlive: 30 * time.Second,
            }).DialContext,
            TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true}, // Отключение проверки сертификатов

        }

        httpClient := &http.Client{
            Transport: httpTransport,
        }

        req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://httpbin.org/get", nil)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error creating request:", err)
            continue
        }

        resp, err := httpClient.Do(req)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error making request with proxy", proxyStr, ":", err)
            continue
        }

        fmt.Println("Proxy", proxyStr, "is working.")

        defer resp.Body.Close()

        err = saveResponseToFile(resp.Body, "response.html")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error writing response to file:", err)
            continue
        }
    }
}


Если включена проверка сертификатов TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true} возникают следующие ошибки:
Error proxy 45.82.179.153:33354 : Get "https://httpbin.org/get": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp 45.82.179.153:33354: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
Error proxy 3.127.62.252:80 : Get "https://httpbin.org/get": local error: tls: bad record MAC
Error proxy 52.16.232.164:3128 : Get "https://httpbin.org/get": local error: tls: bad record MAC
Error proxy 13.38.176.104:3128 : Get "https://httpbin.org/get": local error: tls: bad record MAC
Error proxy 44.204.37.158:8081 : Get "https://httpbin.org/get": local error: tls: bad record MAC
Error proxy 3.96.173.26:59878 : Get "https://httpbin.org/get": local error: tls: bad record MAC
Error proxy 20.111.54.16:80 : Get "https://httpbin.org/get": proxyconnect tcp: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake
Error proxy 20.111.54.16:8123 : Get "https://httpbin.org/get": proxyconnect tcp: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake

Если отключена проверка сертификатов TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: false} возникают следующие ошибки:
Error proxy 45.82.179.153:33354 : Get "https://httpbin.org/get": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp 45.82.179.153:33354: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
Error proxy 3.127.62.252:80 : Get "https://httpbin.org/get": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
Error proxy 52.16.232.164:3128 : Get "https://httpbin.org/get": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
Error proxy 13.38.176.104:3128 : Get "https://httpbin.org/get": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
Error proxy 44.204.37.158:8081 : Get "https://httpbin.org/get": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
Error proxy 3.96.173.26:59878 : Get "https://httpbin.org/get": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Моя цель реализовать нормальную обработку исключений при работе с прокси, однако из-за этой проблемы с сертификатами не могу продолжить свой основной проект где и хотел реализовать работу с прокси.
Мне по сути без разницы будет ли проводиться проверка сертификатов (скрипт пишу для себя), главное что бы можно было нормально работать с прокси и выполнять запросы.
Вполне вероятно, что проблема связанна с прокси, однако тогда при отключенной проверке сертификатов запросы должны проходить нормально, но увы этого не происходит.
В данный момент я не нашел как не проводить проверку сертификатов и выполнять запрос через прокси или же как их проверять без ошибок. Я уже пробовал следующие с тем же результатом:

Получал копию пула системных сертификатов x509.SystemCertPool() и определял набор корневых сертификатов в tls.Config httpTransport.TLSClientConfig = &tls.Config{RootCAs:x509.NewCertPool()}
Добавлял клиентский сертификат сайта в копию пула системных сертификатов
Использовал не стандартный пакет для отправки запросов github.com/go-resty/resty/v2 и  golang.org/x/net/proxy
Выполнял запросы на десяток разных сайтов.
Запускал скрипт на: виртуалке windows, другом пк
Еще на стаке нашел как включали игнорирование следующим образом (то же не помогло):

insecureSSLCustom := flag.Bool("insecure-ssl", true, "Accept/Ignore all server SSL certificates")
flag.Parse()
config := &tls.Config{
    InsecureSkipVerify: *insecureSSLCustom,
    RootCAs:            rootCAs,
}

Использую:

go 1.21.3
Windows 11, Windows 10
Тип прокси HTTPS без авторизации


(оффтоп) вот недавно дописывал парсер на голанге, такие же ошибки вылезали, всю голову поломал почему не работают прокси при переходе на некоторые сайты, в итоге решил всё тем, что воткнул на локальную машину openvpn, а на сервере (зарубежном) и так работало всё. Для начала проверь работает ли всё у тебя на сервере, проблема локальная или везде такие проблемы возникают, и что за локация на сервере на котором работает скрипт.

Весь код тестировал у себя на пк. На сервере еще не пробовал. Сейчас проверил работы через outline VPN увы ничего не поменялось. Вечером попробую на сервере

Проверил на двух серверах, убунту и дэбиан. Все равно выводит те же ошибка, не понимаю что не так делаю
